# How to fix the error from my unit-testing class?

Tags: java, database, unit-testing, exception, netbeans

I have an homework where I need to create a J2EE application web. In my team, I'm the one that need to prepare the unit-tests, but I have a lots of errors in them and I don't know how to solve them so I would like to request some help please.

Class Customer:

```
public class Customer {

private int CustomerID;
private String email;

public int getCustomerID() {
    return CustomerID;
}

public void setCustomerID(int CustomerID) {
    this.CustomerID = CustomerID;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

}
```

Class CustomerDAO:

```
private final DataSource myDataSource;
public CustomerDAO(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.myDataSource = dataSource;
}


public Customer LoginCustomer(int customerID, String email) throws DAOException {
    Customer result = null;

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = ? AND EMAIL = ?";
    try (Connection connection = myDataSource.getConnection(); 
        PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {

        stmt.setInt(1, customerID);
                    stmt.setString(2, email);

        try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
            if (rs.next()) {
                String name = rs.getString("NAME");
                String address = rs.getString("ADDRESSLINE1");

                result = new Customer();
                                    result.setCustomerID(customerID);
                                    result.setEmail(email);
            } 
        }
    }  catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger("DAO").log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        throw new DAOException(ex.getMessage());
    }

    return result;
}
}
```

Class DAO:

```
public class DAO {

private final DataSource myDataSource;

public DAO(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.myDataSource = dataSource;
}
    public int addOrder(int ordernum, int idcustomer, int   idproduct, int quantity, int shippingcost, Date salesDate, Date shippingDate, String company) throws SQLException {
    int result = 0;
    String sql = "INSERT INTO PURCHASE_ORDER VALUES=(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ";
    try (Connection connection = myDataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        stmt.setInt(1, ordernum);
        stmt.setInt(2, idcustomer);
        stmt.setInt(3, idproduct);
        stmt.setInt(4, quantity);
        stmt.setInt(5, shippingcost);
        stmt.setDate(6, (java.sql.Date) salesDate);
        stmt.setDate(7, (java.sql.Date) shippingDate);
        stmt.setString(8, company);
        result = stmt.executeUpdate();
    }
    return result;
}
public int deleteOrder(int OrderNum) throws SQLException {
    int result = 0;
    String sql = "DELETE FROM PURCHASE_ORDER WHERE ORDER_NUM = ?";
    try (Connection connection = myDataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        stmt.setInt(1, OrderNum);
        result = stmt.executeUpdate();
    }
    return result;
}
public int changeOrder(int Qte, int ordernum) throws SQLException {
    int result=0;
    String sql = "UPDATE PURCHASE_ORDER SET QUANTITY = ? WHERE ORDER_NUM=?";
    try (Connection connection = myDataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        stmt.setInt(1, Qte);
        stmt.setInt(2, ordernum);
        result=stmt.executeUpdate();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Class DataSouceFactory:

```
public class DataSourceFactory {

public enum DriverType {
    embedded, server
};

// Choic du type de driver : embedded ou serveur
private static final DriverType TYPE = DriverType.embedded;

/**
 * Renvoie la source de données (server ou embbeded)
 *
 * @return la source de données
 */
public static DataSource getDataSource() {

    ds.setDatabaseName("sample");
    ds.setUser("app");
    ds.setPassword("app");
    // The host on which Network Server is running
    ds.setServerName("localhost");
    // port on which Network Server is listening
    ds.setPortNumber(1527);
    return ds;
}

}
```

Class Product:
    public class Product {

```
private int idproduct;
private int idmanufacturer;
private String productcode;
private int purchasecost;
private int quantityonhand;
private int markup;
private String available;
private String description;

public Product(int idproduct, int idmanufacturer, String productcode, int purchasecost, int quantityonhand, int markup, String available, String description){
    this.idproduct=idproduct;
    this.idmanufacturer=idmanufacturer;
    this.productcode=productcode;
    this.purchasecost=purchasecost;
    this.quantityonhand=quantityonhand;
    this.markup=markup;
    this.available=available;
    this.description=description;
}

//GETTER

public int getIdProduct() {
    return idproduct;
}

public int getIdManufacturer(){
    return idmanufacturer;
}

public String getProductCode(){
    return productcode;
}

public int getPurchaseCost(){
    return purchasecost;
}

public int getQuantityOnHand(){
    return quantityonhand;
}

public int getMarkup(){
    return markup;
}

public String getAvailable(){
    return available;
}

public String getDescription(){
    return description;
}
}
```

Class PurchaseOrder:

```
public class PurchaseOrder {

private int ordernum;
private int idcustomer;
private int idproduct;
private int quantity;
private int shippingcost;
private Date salesDate;
private Date shippingDate;
private String company;

public PurchaseOrder(int ordernum, int idcustomer, int idproduct, int quantity, int shippingcost, Date salesDate, Date shippingDate, String company) {
    this.ordernum=ordernum;
    this.idcustomer=idcustomer;
    this.idproduct=idproduct;
    this.quantity=quantity;
    this.shippingcost=shippingcost;
    this.salesDate=salesDate;
    this.shippingDate=shippingDate;
    this.company=company;
}

//GETTER

public int getOrderNumber() {
    return ordernum;
}

public int getIdCustomer() {
    return idcustomer;
}

public int getIdProduct(){
    return idproduct;
}

public int getShippingCost(){
    return shippingcost;
}


public Date getSalesDate() {
    return salesDate;
}

public Date getShippingDate() {
    return shippingDate;
}

public String getCompany() {
    return company;
}



}
```

Class DAOException:

```
public class DAOException extends Exception {

/**
 * Creates a new instance of <code>DAOException</code> without detail
 * message.
 */
public DAOException() {
}

/**
 * Constructs an instance of <code>DAOException</code> with the specified
 * detail message.
 *
 * @param msg the detail message.
 */
public DAOException(String msg) {
    super(msg);
}
}
```

Unit-testing class:

```
public class DAOTest {

private DAO myDAO;
private DataSource myDataSource;
private static Connection myConnection;

/**
 * Test for the data base
 */
@Before
//Test la création de la BDD.
public void createBDD() throws SQLException {
    myDataSource = getDataSource();
    myConnection = myDataSource.getConnection();
    myDAO = new DAO(myDataSource);
}

@After
//Test la destruction de la BDD.
public void deleteBDD() throws SQLException {
    myConnection.close();
    myDAO = null;
}

@Test
//Test le remplissage de la BDD à partir d'un fichier sql.
private void fillBDD(String file, Connection myConnection) throws SQLException {
    String path = DAOTest.class.getResource(file).getFile();
    SqlFile fileSQL = new SqlFile(new File(path));
    fileSQL.setConnection(myConnection);
    fileSQL.execute();
    fileSQL.closeReader();
}

/**
 * Test for the class dataSourceFactory
 */
//Test l'acquisition de la source de donnée.
@Test
public void getDataSource() throws DAOException {
    org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource ds = new org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource();
    ds.setDatabase("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testcase;shutdown=true");
    ds.setUser("username");
    ds.setPassword("password");
    return ds;
}

/**
 * Test for the class CustomerDAO
 */
@Test
// Test si le login fonctionne
public void logIN() throws DAOException {
    int customerID = 1;
    String email = "test@example.com";
    assertEquals(customerID, myDAO.identification(email));
}

/**
 * Test for the class ???
 */
@Test
//Test le calcule du prix du produit.
public void finalPrice() {
    float price = 10;
    int quantity = 1;
    float discountRate = 0;
    float shippingcost = 10;
    float markup = 0;
    assertEquals(price * quantity * 0.01 * (1 - discountRate) + shippingcost, "Méthode qui calcule le prix final");
}
}
```

I don't know if it can help, but we made a git for it here: https://github.com/Selena00/ProjetTechnoWeb

Well the first problem that I have in the unit-testing classs is the fact that when I do a "throws DAOException", I have an error conserning its location.

Same in with "private DAO myDAO", it says that the symbol DAO can't be found. And that problem is present everywhere where I create a new "DAO".
Again I have a problem with the test "fillBDD", where it again says that the symbol SqlFile isn't found.

Finally in the test "getDataSource", it says in the first line that the package org.hsqlsb.jsbc does not exist.

In all of the above case, the only thing that it proposed me was to search for depencies in the Maven repositories but without success.

Afterwards if some people can give me some advice about how to do the tests: "addOrder", "deleteOrder" and "changeOrder", I would really be grateful. For those three tests I don't know how to begin :/.

Thanks in advance for those who would take the time to help me :D.

Comment: Did you write this code yourself? If it was given to you, was it meant to compile? You mention homework and team, check with one of your peers if they know how to compile the code, since that clearly is your problem. If you code, for e.g. depends on org.hsqlsb.jsbc then that package must be in place for you application to build. And when it comes to unit test, it kind of needs compiling code. But you will need to figure out how to mock the DB layer to write the tests.

Comment: 'k thanks, I'll try to speak to my friends :D

Comment: Well then with my group we could manage to delete all errors besides the sql one. Do you have any ideas about it please ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular How do [I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). **--** For *unit testing* (in contrast to application testing done with JUnit) you need to use a *mocking framework* (like [mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito)) to test you code in isolation.